# Earthquake simulation - finite elements method (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, finite-element-analysis

do you know is there's a way to simulate a earthquake with the finite elements method using the Partial Differential Equation Toolbox on Matlab ?
My goal is to visualize the amplitude of a (Rayleigh) wave in all points of a forest for different frequencies. And if possible to see what are the modes of vibration of the trees.
Maybe this is a silly question but I'm getting started.
Thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to figure out how to express the boundary conditions that will represent your earthquake.  I think the root cause is one tectonic plate sliding over another.  Are you modeling a single plate?  Is this a 2D planar model or 3D?  You need to think less about Matlab and more about the physics.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for your answer. Yes of course, but Matlab has good tools for finite elements analysis. Actually I wanted to use a simpler model : a Rayleigh wave instead of simulating tectonic plates. And I need a 3D model because I expect the trees to have bending modes.

Comment: Ideally, it would look something like that : zupimages.net/up/22/19/eadu.png

Comment: Okay, how do you represent a Rayleigh wave boundary condition in your 3D FEA model?  Shear, compression, or a combination?

Comment: Ideally a combinaison but I could try with compression or shear alone first.

Comment: This is a hyperbolic equation.  I would advise applying time-varying displacement boundary conditions on one of your 3D boundary planes.  The nodes on the z = 0 plane should receive z(t) = zmax*sin(2*pi*fz*t), x(t) = xmax*sin(2*pi*fx*t) displacements.  Pick max displacement magnitudes and frequencies.  Use Fourier series if it's more complex loading.